# javascript sizing content relative to window size

Tags: javascript, window, height

I want my content to have height = window.height() of the maximized window.  How can I get window.height() of the maximized window when the window is not maximized?  When I use screen.availheight my content gets cutoff at the bottom in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Use a function to resize your content window when the browser is resized...

```
function resize() {
    var ht;
           var objDiv = document.getElementById("[YOUR DIV]");

           if (typeof window.innerHeight != 'undefined') {
            ht = window.innerHeight
           } else if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined' && typeof  document.documentElement.clientHeight != 'undefined' && document.documentElement.clientHeight != 0) {
        ht = document.documentElement.clientHeight
    }

           objDiv.style.height = (ht - 100) + 'px';
           return objDiv;
}
```

And then call this somewhere...

```
onresize="resize();
```